# Ajax in webview not send data to server

Tags: android, ajax, webview

The ajax in webview works fine if you keep using it, but if you don't do anything and wait for about 10 minutes and try to use ajax to send data to server nothing happens. I checked the server side there is no request sent from the ajax in webview. Is it bug of webview or did I mess something up?

The ajax code I use (the jQuery `$.ajax` with some my own functions):

```
function extendBaseAjax(paramObj){
if(typeof(paramObj['maxRetryTimes'])=='undefined'){
    paramObj['maxRetryTimes']=0;
}
var maxRetryTimes=paramObj['maxRetryTimes'];
var retryCounter=0;
var error=paramObj['error'];  
var errorHandler=function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
    if(textStatus=='timeout'){
        retryCounter+=1;
        if(retryCounter<maxRetryTimes){
            $.ajax(paramObj);
        }else{
            error(textStatus);//timeout", "error", "notmodified" ,"parsererror"
        }
    }else{
        error(textStatus);
    }
}


var success=paramObj.success;

var successHandler=function(data){
    if(typeof(data)=="string"){
        data=eval('('+data+')');
    }
    success(data);
    }

    paramObj['success']=successHandler;
    paramObj['error']=errorHandler;
    paramObj['date']=new Date().getTime();//no cache
    $.ajax(paramObj);
}
```

And most of my ajax use like this:

```
        extendJsonpAjax({
        url:url,
        data:data,
        timeout:timeout,
        maxRetryTimes:maxRetryTimes,
        success:function(data){
            var resultNumber=data['resultNumber'];
            totalPageNumber=resultNumber+1
            totalPageNumber=Math.ceil(resultNumber/limit);
            executeCallBack(data,currentPageNumber,totalPageNumber);
            isAjaxCompleted=true;
        },
        error:function(textStatus){
            errorCallBack(textStatus);
            isAjaxCompleted=true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is very hard to diagnose a problem that could be related to code if you don't post any. You may want to post your ajax code and maybe even how you are loading it in the webview.

Comment: i tried my app on android 2.2 and it is all ok.
i think it is something wrong with android 1.5
and i will edit the question to post the ajax code,but i think the ajax code is fine,it works normal on pc.